# PHP: How to check if changing model is allowed to member of a given group

Tags: php, security, user-roles

In the app that I'm working on each user can belong to one or more of the groups, e.g. 'guest', 'member', 'admin' etc.

When user applies action that changes model, e.g. registering account, editing someone's post, etc, I need to verify if user is allowed to do this.

Actions in turn can have an owner (or subject) who is allowed to execute it. For example, registration and login actions subject is `guest`, logout subject is `member` (meaning logged-in member), editing post action subject is `owner`.

Right now I do it a la Apache allow,deny rules:
- each method has a list of user roles that are allowed to use it
- each of these roles has 3 attributes:

`order` ("allow,deny" or "deny,allow")

`allow` - with list of roles of subject (who can be different from current user), e.g. owner, guest, member, admin, etc, who are allowed to use it

`deny` - same as above, but subject roles who are not allowed to use it

Function `isAllowed` has this logic:

Gets groups of current user and subject.

If current user ID = subject user ID, it adds 'owner' to groups of both current user and subject.

If none of current user's groups listed in method's user roles, function returns false.

Else function goes on to check if subject's groups are in allow or deny lists and applies order (allow/deny) logic.

If there's more than 1 result (e.g. subject user is both member and admin), I apply subordination logic (where each role has a numeric value of importance, so I can know that being admin is a more important position that being a regular member) and pick result (allow or deny) for the most important role.

Does this make sense? What should I change?

Comment: I have a db scheme for that matter, if you're interested.

Comment: also, any specific environment? (framework, ..)

Comment: Sure I'm interested, but is DB necessary? It's not a framework, but it's an MVC-like PHP app.

Comment: @yoda
I am interested if you can post it here.

Comment: @SIFE, @SODA, http://aeon-dev.org/db.png (Ignore the unecessary stuff, and some things are hidden, but the scheme works pretty well)

Answer (score 0):

I would load the users' group into their session. Then when you get to a function that requires a certain group permission, do an if on the session variable to see if it matches.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php